# I loved developing a 2D game(C++ SDL), but i am not good at maths/physics

Tags: c++, math, game-development, physics

I developed 2 games in C++ using SDL. Without using any wrappers. I literally loved and enjoyed every part of the journey. Complex algorithms, how 2D works, rendering, audio, input etc. But i am not too good at maths and specially physics.

PS: There are drag and drop tools and IDE available for game development, i am not talking about them, i love low level programming specially C++ and assembly.

Comment: While off-topic, I would encourage you to consider something that I only realized when I went back to college to study computing: all those algorithms, data structures, and logic? That's actually math. You have way more mathematical aptitude and knowledge than you think, it's just that you acquired it in a way you didn't recognize as math, because it isn't hand-performed algebra or calculus. Discrete Math, Algorithms, Logic, Boolean Algebra, Topology, and more - if you you can get past them mental block of thinking you aren't good at math, I bet you'll be surprised how far you can go.

Comment: @BrianHall very true. Once you learn abstraction, everything else is details. ;)

Comment: @BrianHall such a generous answer! thanks i will explore more.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a **[physics engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine)**. You can learn just enough math to use it. You don't have to make your own. They do neat things like collisions, gravity, and Brownian motion. They can be a lot of fun when used well. Don't ask us to recommend one. We don't do that here.